# Regex with multiple backslash match in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract http status codes from a log file. The log file stores code is below format:

```
[Some log]{\""status\"": \""401\"",[Some further log]
```

I have written below regex through which I am able to search the codes in log file via atom/notepad++:

```
\\\"\"status\\\"\"\:\ \\\"\"[4-9][0-9][0-9]\\\"\"
```

However its not working in my python code. Code is as below:

```
*import csv, os, re
from re import search
pattern = re.compile(r'\\\"\"status\\\"\"\:\ \\\"\"[4-9][0-9][0-9]\\\"\"')
print(pattern)
#outfile = open("output.txt", 'a')
with open('query_data.csv') as logfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(logfile)
    filtered_log = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        source = row[21]
        result = pattern.search(source)
        print(result)
        if result != None:
            print(result)*
```

row[21] is the message column which contains the log. Any reply would be helpful.

Comment: Just remove the `r` from your string as it has backslashes escaped already. i.e. `pattern = re.compile('\\\"\"status\\\"\"\:\ \\\"\"[4-9][0-9][0-9]\\\"\"')`

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the response. Still it doesn't help and I am getting the same.

Comment: It works fine here: https://rextester.com/BYB74163

Answer (score 0):

In fact,You dont have to use regEx,Why not try something simpler like this:

```py
string = '[Some log]{\""status\"": \""401\"",[Some further log]'

lines = string.split("\\")

print(lines)

# ['[Some log]{""status"": ""401"",[Some further log]']
```